# Play data on incoming sco socket

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to write an Android app which reads data drom sco socket and play on speaker. At the same time it reads data from mic and send on connected sco connection. `setbluetoothsco(on)` doesn't do the trick for me. As per my understanding, we need to set mic as input device and speaker as output device for all data coming on sco socket. How to proceed about this?

Answer (score 0):

The default device for [STREAM_MUSIC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_MUSIC) should be the internal loudspeaker, unless you've connected a wired accessory or paired the phone with an A2DP accessory. You can specify that stream type e.g. for an AudioTrack.

To use the internal mic you can specify [MIC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html) as the audio source for your AudioRecord/MediaRecorder.

setbluetoothsco is not what you want. What that'll do is force routing of some stream types to the BT SCO accessory.

AFAIK the SCO link only has bandwidth for 8 kHz mono full duplex audio, so whatever you play in the loudspeaker coming through SCO will probably sound pretty bad. You're probably well aware of that already, but I thought I should mention it.